# How to perform actions on Drupal taxonomy term creation?

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, hook

I am currently working on a Drupal 7 project and I need to build a module which requires me to perform an action (populate a custom database table) whenever a new taxonomy term is created in a certain vocabulary. What is the best practice for this? Is there any hook that i could use? What are my options here?

Module description: 
The admin needs to be able to assign an email address for every term created in that certain vocabulary on the module configuration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start looking at

hook_taxonomy_term_insert

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7

and

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/7

Comment: I just want to detect when a term has been inserted. Can someone explain this ?

Comment: When you hook into the hook_taxonomy_term_insert your code will always be executed. Since that is what hook is being called when a term is inserted / saved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too familiar with Drupal API and coding you can always use Rules module who has nice UI and gives you a lot of functionalities. It gives you possibility to create conditional actions on some events, as for example "Send email after node is updated". With this module you can create a lot of custom events, conditions and actions.

Here is the link of Rules module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/rules

You need to enable Rules UI module to be able to use Rules module in UI.